# Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "string" em "(UnityEngine.GameObject gameObject, string tag)"

Tags: unity3d, unity-5, unity2d

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    switch (collision.gameObject,tag)
    {
        case "loot":
            Item item = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Loot>().item;
            CoreGame._instace.inventory.GetItem(item, 1);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        break;
```

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que você tenha confundido, collision.gameObject,tag por collision.gameObject.tag, basicamente, é só trocar a vírgula pelo ponto.